# Will it be possible to add an extra hard disk or change the hard disk by increasing the size on my macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro

My disk space is full and keep getting alert message.

Will it be possible to add an extra hard disk or change the hard disk by increasing the size on my macbook?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably yes. Almost all MacBooks, except for some newer ones, have upgradable storage. If you want to see if you can upgrade yours, I would look up your MacBook on [EveryMac.com](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/). It uses your serial number, which can be found by clicking the Apple logo on the left end of the menu bar, and selecting "*About This Mac*".

Once at EveryMac.com, scroll down to the Storage selection where it will specify if it can be upgraded. Alternatively, you could Google your MacBook once you've identified it.

Comment: goofy didn't state what model MacBook however you said "_I don't know a Macbook you can't upgrade the storage on_", well the Mid 2010 MacBook was the last model MacBook that has separate removal storage in the form of HDD or SSD. All MacBooks beyond that have onboard flash storage and is not considered user replaceable per se because you'd replace the entire primary logic board to do.

Comment: Not quite: MacBook Pro with Retina Display ("mid 2012" to "mid 2015") and MacBook Air ("late 2010" to "early 2015") [all have user-replaceable SSDs](https://9to5mac.com/2015/02/24/upgrade-ssd-macbook-air-retina-macbook-pro/). The USB-C generation of MacBook Pro and (12") MacBook are the first to have storage completely integrated/soldered onto the primary logic board.

Comment: @Merlin, This question is about a MacBook, **not** MacBook Pro or MacBook Air!

Comment: @user3439894, given the level of detail provided by the original questioner (no macOS version, alert text, or even capitalization on MacBook), I think it's safe to assume that "MacBook" here meant "my Apple laptop" rather than "MacBook5,2/6,1/7,1/8,1/9,1... [guess which](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201608)". But if we read the questioner more literally, then yes, your point is correct. :-)